# *ngFor not working on html even if the variable exist

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

This should be basic stuff but somehow Im struggling

table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableTitle = 'Table';
  tableHeaders = [
    'Project',
    'Budget',
    'Status',
    'Users',
    'Completion',
    'Actions'
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

table.component.html

```
 <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
    <thead class="thead-light">
       <tr *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">
          <th scope="col">{{header}}</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
....
```

is not showing anything....I tried to add the headers with some static values like `<th scope="col"> Hello world </th>` and works fine....also tried to print something like this

```
<table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">{{tableHeaders[0]}}</th>
      <th scope="col">{{tableHeaders[1]}}</th>
      <th scope="col">{{tableHeaders[2]}}</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

and again works fine so the var is present in the html.....but when trying it to put it through the *ngFor it doesn't show anything...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table.component.html code you are using has the repeat (*ngFor) on the wrong element - you are creating multiple tr's - each with one th.

You should have the *ngFor on the `th` to create multiple `th's` within the one tr of the thead.

```
 <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
    <thead class="thead-light">
       <tr>
          <th scope="col" *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">{{header}}</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

I have added a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3eevgn - thank you to @Oussail for the blitz- I modified the code to suit from that original :)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of *ngFor in component.html file is not right. *ngFor doesn't work with `tr`.
You must have to use *ngFor on `th` for creating multiple `th` instead of `tr`.

```
<table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
    <thead class="thead-light">
       <tr>
          <th scope="col" *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">{{header}}</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Hopefully it works for you in much better way. Thanks